# Show development and test site with same domain on browser

Tags: domain, hosts, hosts-file

I have a situation where domain.com (is the live server - A record points to this server). We have another domain.com (which is the test server - users manually set hosts file).

Users would like to access the live and test sites simultaneously on the the browser. What is the best way to do this? Users use their PCs/Macs to view the site.

I know that if you set the Hosts file setting on the PC then you can decide which IP to use that works but then switching hosts file each time is pretty hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/HostsFile

It's a Firefox addon that allows you to switch between different hosts file (and also do the DNS cache cleanup).

What we do on my job is to have subdomains for every environment like `dev.domain.com` or `staging.domain.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use firefox get this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/HostsFile

If not your best bet is using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) which act as a web proxy and thus can use his own hosts file ("Tools" Menu, "HOSTS File"), there's even a function to proxy for multiple remote clients.

NB: Fiddler is an excellent tool, it supports addons and many of them ar very useful and easy to use: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/extensions.asp